# Child process inherits nvidia profile from parent

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, optimus

I have an application I'm writing that needs an Nvidia GPU to run because of some advanced OpenGL extensions it's using. I've added a profile in the 3d Settings section of the Nvidia Control panel, and set it to use the High-performance Nvidia processor.

My issue arises on machines with multiple GPUs, say, an on-board Intel and additionally an NVidia gtx 1060. If I run my application standalone, all is fine. However, my application can also be opened through Adobe After Effects (launched via a call to ::system() or the like). And if After Effects is using the on-board (and I cannot control this), then my application will also be told to use the on-board, regardless of its profile in 3d Settings.

1. What is going on here? Why is it inheriting?
2. How can I prevent this, and make sure that my application opens with the Nvidia GPU, regardless of what its parent process opened?